# Efficient root finding algorithm for monotonic function

Tags: computational-geometry, roots

I am trying to find the roots of a monotonic function with as few function evaluations as possible.

I have approximated a manifold with a piece-wise defined polynomial. The manifold is periodic and so I am only considering its unit cell (one period). I split the unit cell, in general, a parallelogram but in this case a square, into triangles.

[image]

I then approximate each sheet of the manifold within each triangle with a unique quadratic polynomial.

[image]

I would like to find the root that satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i}^{\mathrm{sheets}} \sum_{j}^{\mathrm{triangles}} \int p_{i,j}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}C_{i,j} - A = 0
\end{equation}
where $i$ is a sum over the sheets of the manifold, $j$ is a sum over the triangular tiles, $p_{i,j}$ is the second-degree polynomial approximation of the manifold's $i$th sheet within the $j$th tile, and $C_{i,j}$ is the region within a level curve of the polynomial approximation of the manifold's $i$th sheet within the $j$th tile. Here is a plot of the $C_{i,j}$ for each triangle and sheet for some estimate of the root.

[image]

Said another way, I would like to find an isovalue where the area within the level curves of the polynomials, regions where the polynomials are less than the isovalue, is some predetermined value $A$.

At the moment I am using the bisection method, which is very slow because at each iteration it takes a significant amount of time to interpolate the manifold and then calculate the level curves and their containing areas. I may have hundreds of triangles and tens of sheets.

I also tried the *regula falsi* method but ran into cases where its convergence was worse than the bisection method.

Comment: Have you tried using marching triangles?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I thought marching triangles was an algorithm for refining boundaries and small features. Can it be used to find roots?

Comment: I meant [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: I haven't tried either because, as far as I know, those aren't root finding algorithms.

Comment: Yes they are not, they are algorithms for finding isovalues.

Comment: I'm open to recommendations. I just don't see how marching squares or triangles is going to help. I don't want to further split the unit cell into smaller triangles. I just want to find an isovalue at which the area within level curves of my polynomial approximation of the manifold has a predetermined value. I want to do this without changing the representation of the manifold.

Comment: Clearly for you to arrive at a fast solution for this problem, you need to make the computation of the area for the level curves across all the manifolds more efficient. Bisection itself is going to be pretty fast if your function evaluations are efficient, so changing the root finding algorithm will likely be not be super useful. To me, one needs to use geometry information from each triangle and manifold to divide and conquer this problem to make function evaluations for the area much cheaper and try to avoid computing level curves whenever necessary. I'll lay out some ideas later.

Comment: Nicely-posed question! I wonder, though, if the code you're currently using is small enough to making a minimum working example from?

Comment: @nicoguaro you didn't give a recommendation but you answered a yes/no question. And the OP answered no.

Comment: @spektr I think the calculating the level curves and areas if fairly efficient but you can let me know if you know of a better way. The quadratic polynomial I mentioned is a quadratic polynomial Bezier surface. The level curves of this surface are conic sections, which can be fit exactly with a rational Bezier curve. I fit a rational Bezier curve to the level curve, sample the Bezier curve, and construct a polygon from the sampling points to approximate the area within the level curve. I then use the shoelace algorithm to calculate the area.

Comment: @Richard my code, which is supposed to be a minimum working example, is fairly large at around 2,000 lines.

Comment: @jerjorg I think the algorithm seems reasonable for when you must compute the level curves. However, you may not always need to compute the level curve on a given triangle. If you know that the max value on the triangle is less than an isovalue, then you know this triangle’s area fully contributes. If your isovalue is less than the minimum value of the triangle, then you know that triangle contributes none of its area. Obviously if you precompute the min and max for each triangle, you may avoid the costlier computation you mention above with some simple checks. There’s more you can do too.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, but I recently wrote some code designed specifically for bracketed root-finding on infinitely large intervals on [github](https://github.com/SimpleArt/solver/wiki).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your main concern is bracketing the root in as few iterations as possible, since each iteration is costly. In some cases you have found the regula falsi method to be unreliable, suggesting the bounds on the root may be large or the function cannot be linearly approximated easily. To handle such cases without being significantly slower than bisection, you may want to try [Brent's method](https://youtu.be/-bLSRiokgFk). It uses a combination of bisection and concepts similar to the regula falsi method to give faster convergence when possible.

If you are certain the root should be simple, and Chandrupatla's method could be used instead. In my experience it tends to be faster than Brent's method when initial iterations benefit most from bisection.

If you do not need this much speed, the Illinois method may also suffice. It's a modification of the regula falsi method which greatly improves the rate of convergence and reliability. Though not as fast/reliable as the above algorithms, it is much simpler.

Comment: Are modified regula falsi methods like Illinois or Anderson–Björck as efficient as Brent for monotonic functions?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo : Inverse quadratic interpolation is in general an order better than the secant root (=inverse linear interpolation), so Brent will be better than Illinois.

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo Asymptotically, Brent's method attains a higher order of convergence (usually). It is also more robust due to worst case performance guarantees while regula falsi methods can be influenced by pathological function behavior such as values sharply increasing or plateauing. That said, real use cases usually do not involve finding hundreds of digits of precision, meaning the first few iterations may matter significantly more, and depending on the shape of the graph and your initial interval, Brent's method may be slower. This usually isn't the case though.